# Check if query to DB is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The action method in the controller receive a value, like a couple of letters. The code checks if the table contains any of this letters. I'm using this code for that task:

```
var result = db.People.Where(b => b.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper()));
```

But how can I check if the `result` variable is empty or null, when there are not any matching letters? I tested this, but it's not working!

```
If(result == ""){
// Do something
}
```

I would like to use Viewbag to send a message that there was no match or perhaps do this check in the View. I'm using this with some AJAX and Partial Views and it's working perfect, but I just want show a message if there are not any matches. What is the best way to check if the `result` value is empty or null?

Comment: what is result type?

Comment: `if(result != null){ // all good`

Comment: Hint: check the return value type of [`IEnumerable.Where<TSource>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be by using `!result.Any()`:

```
var result = db.People.Where(b => b.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper()));

If(!result.Any()){
    // Do something
}
```

From MSDN on [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb908973(v=vs.90).aspx):

> **Any()**
>
> Determines whether a sequence contains any elements.

Fits exactly what you need.

Comment: This out of all the answers i think is the best as it answers the question with a simple solution, provides references, and makes intended use of a feature--other solutions require (to me) extra work. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Using `FirstOrDefault` it will give you the first record from the result, else if no result is yielded from the query it returns default value that is `null`,

```
  var result = db.People.Where(b => b.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper())).FirstOrDefault();

  If(result == null){
    // Do something
  }
```

Or if you want to use this result, to manipulate something in your code then you can use the `ToList()`. It will return you list of values and if the query didnt yield anything then the list count will be 0.

```
 var result = db.People.Where(b => b.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper())).ToList();

 If(result.Count == 0){
    // Do something
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because the code is returning an object not a string if you want to return a string then you have to use the "Select" clause to select a specific field and if you want to check in the same code then modify :

> var result = db.People.Where(b => b.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper())).ToList();
>   if(result != null && result.Count > 0)

it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

For IEnumerable we can use Any(), your code will can be written as

```
if(!db.People.Where(b => b.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper())).Any() {
// do some thing
}
```